# flowplayer wowza video not playing

Tags: flowplayer, wowza

I am very new to **flowplayer using wowza** in order to have secure streaming. Below is the code I am using, but video not playing at all. I am pretty sure all files are loading properly without any 404 or 403 errors.

**Here is the code:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Wow! This is video</title>
    <script src="js/flowplayer-3.1.4.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="videos/MyVideo.mp4"
       style="display:block;width:425px;height:300px;"
       id="wowza" class="player">

    <!-- splash image inside the container -->
<img src="./flow_eye.jpg"
    alt="Search engine friendly content" /></a>

    <script language="JavaScript">

        flowplayer("wowza", "swf/flowplayer-3.1.5.swf", {

          log: { level: 'debug', filter: 'org.flowplayer.rtmp.,org.flowplayer.securestreaming.' },

            clip: {
            url: 'mp4:videos/MyVideo.mp4',
            // use RTMP streaming
            provider: 'rtmp',

            // with a secured connection
            connectionProvider: 'secure'
            },

            plugins: {

            // set up the RTMP streaming plugin
            rtmp: {
                url: "swf/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.13.swf",

                // The net connection URL with HDDN looks like this
                netConnectionUrl: 'rtmpte://d.securevod.flowplayervod.netdna-cdn.com:1935/securevod.flowplayervod'
            },

            // set up the secure streaming plugin
            secure: {
                url: "swf/flowplayer.securestreaming-3.2.9.swf",

                // the token value (shared secret).
                token: 'bky9p52t'
            }
            }
        });


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please test it from your end and tell me what still needs to be added in above code.

Answer (score 1):

Your are using wrong script.

what I see, that you are trying to make a live stream using `RTMP(Real Time Messaging Protocol)`. and you want to play just video.

well incase of `flow-player` you don't need to re-invent the wheel. 
just use any sample script.

[Embed Videos in your Web Pages with Flowplayer](http://michaelsoriano.com/embed-videos-with-flowplayer/)

Comment: there is a solution to hide video url.
please view the [main page](https://flowplayer.org/i/flowplayer/setup_configuration)